# SQL Server : Recursive function to get last working day

Tags: sql-server, function, recursion

I have a list holidays stored in BankHolidays table for a couple of years. Now i need to compute the last working day for any given date.

CTE may help in this scenario, however i prefer to have this snippet as a function.

I have written the following (pseudo) code to get my result, but i'm not able to do a recursive call

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_Previous_Working_Day(@Day date) RETURNS date
AS BEGIN
if(datename(dw,@Day) = 'Sunday')
    set @Day = DATEADD(day, -1, @Day)

if(datename(dw,@Day) = 'Saturday')
    set @Day = DATEADD(day, -1, @Day)

if not exists (select count(1) from BankHolidays where datepart(yyyy,HolidayDate) = datepart(yyyy,@Day))
    return null
else
begin
    if exists (select count(1) from BankHolidays where convert(date,HolidayDate) = convert(date,@Day))
    begin
        set @Day = DATEADD(day, -1, @Day)
        dbo.Get_Previous_Working_Day(@Day) --This recurise call may need to be modified
    end
    else
        return @Day
 end
end
```

Thank you in advance

---

**Edit 1**

Error : Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

I guess this is due to the stack over flow on recursive calls and its not able to decide when to quit. Seems like a logical error. Unfortunately i couldn't figure where its going wrong

```
BankHolidays Table:
--------------------------------------------------
HolidayDate     DayofWeek   Description
--------------------------------------------------
2015-01-01      Thursday    New year
2010-01-01      Friday      New year
2015-04-03      Friday      Good Friday
2015-05-04      Monday      Early May bank holiday
2014-06-11      Wednesday   June 14 - NEW ENTRY
2015-05-25      Monday      Spring bank holiday
2015-12-28      Monday      Boxing Day (substitute day)
2015-04-06      Monday      Easter Monday
2015-08-31      Monday      Summer bank holiday
2015-12-25      Friday      Christmas Day
```

Expected Output

```
Get_Previous_Working_Day('2015-01-01')  -- Result : 2014-12-31
Get_Previous_Working_Day('2015-01-02')  -- Result : 2014-12-31
Get_Previous_Working_Day('2010-01-04')  -- Result : 2009-12-31
Get_Previous_Working_Day('2015-04-06')  -- Result : 2015-04-02
Get_Previous_Working_Day('2015-12-05')  -- Result : 2015-12-04
Get_Previous_Working_Day('2015-12-06')  -- Result : 2015-04-04
Get_Previous_Working_Day('2014-06-12')  -- Result : 2014-06-10
```

Comment: What's the error you get? The design of BankHoliday and some sample data and calls would also help.

Comment: why you do not have a column in your BankHolidays-Table that stores a pre-calculated value of the last working day? So you would not need a recursive call.

Comment: @flo: Error is where i'm making the recursive calls. may be im missing how to call the same function back. I have edited my question with table values and sample output required

Comment: @CPMunich : I appreciate the idea and having pre-calculated last working day would help. i fear i cannot change the table design. Even if i could, at some point of time to compute the value of previous working day i need to go thought the same process of making sure the computed working day is not listed in table and not a weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BankHolidays
(
    HolidayDate DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    [DayofWeek] AS DATENAME(dw, HolidayDate),
    [Description] VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.BankHolidays (HolidayDate, [Description])
VALUES
    ('2015-01-01', 'New year'),
    ('2010-01-01', 'New year'),
    ('2015-04-03', 'Good Friday'),
    ('2015-05-04', 'Early May bank holiday'),
    ('2014-06-11', 'June 14 - NEW ENTRY'),
    ('2015-05-25', 'Spring bank holiday'),
    ('2015-12-28', 'Boxing Day (substitute day)'),
    ('2015-04-06', 'Easter Monday'),
    ('2015-08-31', 'Summer bank holiday'),
    ('2015-12-25', 'Christmas Day')
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_Previous_Working_Day
(
    @date DATE
)
RETURNS DATE
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @result DATE

    ;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT dt = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @date)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, dt)
        FROM cte
        WHERE dt > DATEADD(DAY, -30, @date)
    )
    SELECT TOP(1) @result = dt
    FROM cte
    WHERE dt NOT IN (SELECT t.HolidayDate FROM dbo.BankHolidays t)
        AND DATENAME(dw, dt) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
    ORDER BY dt DESC
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

    RETURN @result


END
GO

SELECT dbo.Get_Previous_Working_Day('2015-12-29')
```

Comment: Perfect suit for my use case. Works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Ramu,

Please find the corrected part here.
There are two issues in the function definition. One is in the calling of function. Since the function should be called by using SELECT statement so you have to use that. 
Second, the function should end by return statement.

So the correct definition would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_Previous_Working_Day(@Day date) RETURNS date
AS BEGIN
if(datename(dw,@Day) = 'Sunday')
    set @Day = DATEADD(day, -1, @Day)

if(datename(dw,@Day) = 'Saturday')
    set @Day = DATEADD(day, -1, @Day)

if not exists (select count(1) from BankHolidays where datepart(yyyy,HolidayDate) = datepart(yyyy,@Day))
    return null
else
begin
    if exists (select count(1) from BankHolidays where convert(date,HolidayDate) = convert(date,@Day))
    begin
        set @Day = DATEADD(day, -1, @Day)
        select @Day = dbo.Get_Previous_Working_Day(@Day) --This recurise call may need to be modified
        return @Day
    end
    else
        return @Day
 end
return @Day
end
```

Comment: I have modified the code as per your suggestion and posted again. I'm able to get rid of the syntax errors now. But im getting another kind of error. Please refere to the error details as updated in the question